# HTML side by side DIV positioning

Tags: css, html, position

Consider this JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/GFsgq/5/ (you may have to zoom out a bit).

It shows a layout that I'm trying to achieve. So far it's been going alright, but I've hit a roadblock. I want to position two divs 77px in height side by side of the centered divs. They need to retain width to always touch the edge of the screen and their center div. I'm not sure how to do this with my limited knowledge of CSS, short of adding properties at random.

Her is a picture to help you understand: http://i49.tinypic.com/2ntz34n.png
The blue strips are where I want the divs to be. How do I achieve this?

Comment: Do the left and right divs you are trying to create have to be seperate divs? or couldnt you just use a larger div spanning the entire width of the page with the center bits as children?

Comment: They need to be separate divs, unfortunately.

Comment: http://i48.tinypic.com/b8tqn4.png - 404 error..

Comment: Not for me, strange. I'll upload it somewhere else in a second.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add this in your CSS:

```
header:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  background-color: blue;
  width: 100%;
  height: 80px;  
}
```

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/GFsgq/32/
fullsrcreen result: http://jsfiddle.net/GFsgq/32/embedded/result/

Comment: Thank you, I knew it couldn't be that complicated. Kudos! :)

Answer (score 0):

i would add parent div spanning thw dith of the screen with position:relative; and to the two child divs use position:absolute; and position one right:0px; and the other left:0px; I am unsure about how you want to distribute width, if you have any other problems then come back.